# Query for xml values in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have xml field in the below table in Data column

ID | website | Data

Following is the xml field

```
<Product>
 <field name="IsCustomer" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>false</boolean>
  </field>
</product>
```

I need to retrieve all the IsCustomer values in my table.

Following is the code part that I tried so far.

```
SELECT EMP.ED.value() as EmployeeID
FROM   [dbo].[Products]
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('/Product/Field[@Name="IsCustomer"]/Boolean') as EMP(ED)
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Sorry. That was my mistake. Its sql server.

Comment: what's the expected output given that sample XML as input? Just `false`?

Comment: I want to get all the field values as separate column. Such as combination of true and false values.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: XML is **strictly case sensitive!** Your XML is not even valid... The leading `<Product>` is another element-name then the closing `</product>`. As you seem to use lower letters in all places, I changed it this way.

Your own query is close, but wrong with some capital letters and you did not use the `.value()`-function properly (missing paramters).

Try this:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,Descr VARCHAR(100),Data XML);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
('Your Sample','<product>
 <field name="IsCustomer" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>false</boolean>
  </field>
</product>')
,('Your sample plus another field','<product>
 <field name="IsCustomer" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>true</boolean>
  </field>
 <field name="SomeOther" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>true</boolean>
  </field>
</product>')
,('No "IsCustomer" at all','<product>
 <field name="SomeOther" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>true</boolean>
  </field>
</product>')
,('Two of them','<product>
 <field name="IsCustomer" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>true</boolean>
  </field>
 <field name="IsCustomer" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>false</boolean>
  </field>
</product>');

SELECT * FROM @mockup;
```

--Your query returning various variants, one of them should be okay for you:

```
SELECT m.ID
      ,m.Descr
      ,fld.value('(boolean/text())[1]','bit')
FROM @mockup AS m
OUTER APPLY m.Data.nodes('/product/field[@name="IsCustomer"]') AS A(fld);
```

Answer (score 1):

I already wrote a post about [XQuerying](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177532/how-does-this-derived-table-with-cross-apply-work/177536#177536) which might be helpful to you.

Note: XQuerying is case sensitive and you need to position yourself properly. Take a look at the post i linked, and if it does not help i will update this comment with a solution regarding your query

Update

---

To answer your question

First and foremost you need to have properly formatted XML, which means tags need to match their case sensitivity, and same rule applies when you are referencing a tag in a XQuery.

So one of the solutions would be :

```
DECLARE @XML as XML
SET @XML = '<Product>
 <field name="IsCustomer" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>false</boolean>
  </field>
</Product>'

SELECT EMP.t.value('boolean[1]','varchar(20)') as EmployeeID
FROM   @XML.nodes('/Product/field') as EMP(t)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.